# Android: How to use LiveData inside doWork method in WorkManager Android

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-workmanager

My requirement is to fetch data from Room DB and return type is LiveData. After fetching data from Room DB, I have to upload to server and delete from DB. I have to do all process in background. Suggest best approach.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fixed, My mistake I was using live data inside WorkManager.

Answer (score 0):

First of all getting data from local db

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM datamodel")
   LiveData<List<DataModel>> getAll();
```

and then upload to server

```
public interface Interface_CreateClass {
    @POST("SetData/CreateClass")
    Call<JsonGet_CreateClass> getJSONCreateClass(@Query("username")
    String username,
    @Body List<ClassSchedule> classSchedule);
}
```

send All data in single object

and then delete data in success response of post

delete like

```
 @Query("DELETE FROM datamodel")
 void deleteAll();
```